# Elementary proof of convergence

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

> Prove that if the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, then
>   $(z_n-z_{n-1})\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

My attempt:

Suppose $\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}z_n= L$, then $\exists$ $\epsilon >0$ such that $\implies$ $|z_n-L|<\epsilon$, $\forall\ n>N$ where $N<n$. Then I get stuck. I know how to prove this for series, but not for sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Choose $N$ really really big so that all the $z_n$ after that point are within $\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ from $L$. How close then are any $z_n$ and $z_{n+1}$ (think triangularly)?

Comment: If, like you said, there is an $N$ big enough such that $z_n$ are within $\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ (i dont know why you divided it by 2 instead of just having the $\epsilon$?) then $z_n$ and $z_{n+1}$ are really close to each other, which then will converge?

Comment: @Q.matin Yes, that's the intuition. But, do some symbol pushing! Try the triangle inequality to show that $|z_{n+1}-z_n|$ is itsy bitsy.

Comment: Hmm, can you give a little more detail for the hint?

Comment: @Q.matin Try applying the triangle inequality with $z_{n+1},z_n$, and $L$.

Comment: What I know from your hint is that $|z_{n+1}-z_n|<\epsilon$ and then using the triangle inequality then $|z_{n+1}-z_n|\le |z_{n+1}|+|z_n|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Q.matin You can stop after your first line! That was true for any $n\geqslant N$. So, you've proven that for any $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $N$ so large that $n\geqslant N$ implies that $|x_n|<\varepsilon$, where $x_n=z_{n+1}-z_n$--this is literally the definition of $x_n\to 0$!

Comment: Ah, so im through with the proof?

Comment: @Q.matin mhmmmm

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

For $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ that verifies
$$
 n\geq N \Rightarrow  |z_n - L| \leq \frac\varepsilon2. 
$$
For any $n$ that verifies $n\geq N$
$$
|z_{n+1}-z_n| = |z_{n+1}-L +L - z_n| \leq |z_{n+1}-L| + |z_n-L| \leq \frac\varepsilon2 + \frac\varepsilon2\leq \varepsilon.
$$